# Populating a column from few textboxes (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a VBA script.
Our teacher has told us to use:

```
ListBox1.AddItem ComboBox1.Text And Val(TextBox4.text) And ListBox1.AddItem
FormatCurrency(price, 2)
```

It is supposed to show both the name from ComboBox1, the quantity from TextBox4 and price from TextBox5 (formatted into 'price' variable) but it gives me an error.

I decided to try to use:

```
ListBox1.AddItem ComboBox1.Text  
ListBox1.AddItem Val(TextBox4.Text)  
ListBox1.AddItem FormatCurrency(price, 2)
```

But the result is this:

[image]

Where as it is supposed to be one next to the other (mew 1 £3.50), instead of one above the other.

Comment: No you are not supposed to use `&` :)

Comment: My friend helped me out, instead of 'And' I was supposed to use '&'

Comment: @Siddharth, it does work that way >.>

Comment: Yes it will work but it will not be aligned. when you have multiple rows :)

Comment: See the answer that I posted. I have updated with the `&` example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the column count and the column width of the listbox in case you want it to behave like a multicolumn listbox.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
    ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "50;50"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ComboBox1.Text  
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Val(TextBox4.Text) 
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = FormatCurrency(price, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Followup from comments.

The reason why you shouldn't use `&` is because the data in columns will not be aligned if you have multiple rows. See this example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem "Sid" & " " & "Rout" & " " & "Sample"
        .AddItem "Hello" & " " & "World" & " " & "Sample"
        .AddItem "Another" & " " & "Example" & " " & "Sample"
        .AddItem "Yet" & " " & "another" & " " & "Sample"
    End With
End Sub
```

And this is what you will get

[image]

Comment: I apologise for replying a year later, I could not register for some reason, and didn't actually need help anymore. The reason I had no problem using '&' was because my course required very basic VBA coding, so using '&' was okay.
Either way, thank you for the help.